# Binary Heap Implementation in Rust

Tags: rust, heap

I'm learning Rust by implementing basic data structures and algorithms. I implemented a binary heap (max heap):

```rust
mod binary_heap {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct MaxHeap<T> {
        pub data: Vec<T>,
    }

    impl<T> MaxHeap<T>
    where
        T: PartialOrd,
    {
        pub fn new() -> MaxHeap<T> {
            MaxHeap { data: vec![] }
        }

        pub fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
            self.data.push(value);
            let new_node_index: usize = self.data.len() - 1;
            self.sift_up(new_node_index);
        }

        pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
            match self.data.len() {
                0 => None,
                _ => {
                    let deleted_node = self.data.swap_remove(0);
                    self.sift_down();
                    Some(deleted_node)
                }
            }
        }

        fn sift_up(&mut self, mut new_node_index: usize) {
            while !self.is_root(new_node_index) && self.is_greater_than_parent(new_node_index) {
                let parent_index = self.parent_index(new_node_index);
                self.data.swap(parent_index, new_node_index);
                new_node_index = self.parent_index(new_node_index);
            }
        }

        fn is_root(&self, node_index: usize) -> bool {
            node_index == 0
        }

        fn is_greater_than_parent(&self, node_index: usize) -> bool {
            let parent_index = self.parent_index(node_index);
            self.data[node_index] > self.data[parent_index]
        }

        fn sift_down(&mut self) {
            let mut sifted_down_node_index: usize = 0;

            while self.has_greater_child(sifted_down_node_index) {
                let larger_child_index = self.calculate_larger_child_index(sifted_down_node_index);
                self.data.swap(sifted_down_node_index, larger_child_index);
                sifted_down_node_index = larger_child_index;
            }
        }

        fn left_child_index(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
            (index * 2) + 1
        }

        fn right_child_index(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
            (index * 2) + 2
        }

        fn parent_index(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
            (index - 1) / 2
        }

        fn has_greater_child(&self, index: usize) -> bool {
            let left_child_index: usize = self.left_child_index(index);
            let right_child_index: usize = self.right_child_index(index);

            self.data.get(left_child_index).is_some()
                && self.data[left_child_index] > self.data[index]
                || self.data.get(right_child_index).is_some()
                    && self.data[right_child_index] > self.data[index]
        }

        fn calculate_larger_child_index(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
            let left_child_index: usize = self.left_child_index(index);
            let right_child_index: usize = self.right_child_index(index);

            let left_child = self.data.get(left_child_index);
            let right_child = self.data.get(right_child_index);

            if ((right_child.is_some() && left_child.is_some()) && right_child > left_child)
                || left_child.is_none()
            {
                return right_child_index;
            } else {
                return left_child_index;
            }
        }
    }

    #[cfg(test)]
    mod test {
        use super::*;

        #[test]
        fn push_test() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(3);
            heap.push(2);

            assert_eq!(vec![3, 2], heap.data);
        }

        #[test]
        fn root_node_is_always_the_biggest_element_in_heap_after_push_test() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(5);
            heap.push(10);
            heap.push(2);

            assert_eq!(10, heap.data[0]);

            heap.push(3);

            assert_eq!(10, heap.data[0]);

            heap.push(20);

            assert_eq!(20, heap.data[0]);
        }

        #[test]
        fn pop_always_pop_the_root_node() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(10);
            heap.push(4);
            heap.push(7);

            heap.pop();

            assert!(!heap.data.contains(&10));
        }

        #[test]
        fn pop_returns_a_variant_of_the_option_enum() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(10);

            assert_eq!(Some(10), heap.pop());
            assert_eq!(None, heap.pop());
        }

        #[test]
        fn root_node_is_always_the_biggest_element_in_heap_after_pop_test() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(5);
            heap.push(10);
            heap.push(2);

            heap.pop();

            assert_eq!(5, heap.data[0]);

            heap.pop();

            assert_eq!(2, heap.data[0]);
        }

        #[test]
        fn heap_is_generic_over_some_type_t() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<(i32, String)> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push((2, String::from("Zanzibar")));
            heap.push((10, String::from("Porto")));
            heap.push((5, String::from("Beijing")));

            let element = heap.pop();

            assert_eq!(Some((10, String::from("Porto"))), element);
            assert_eq!((5, String::from("Beijing")), heap.data[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I'd like to implement a min heap, without duplicating much code and without the need for the client code to always wrap any future elements in a `Reverse` struct.

What can be improved here? Any feedback is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall implementation looks good!

Here are some of my suggestions:

- The field `data` can be private.
- A `as_vec` method can be implemented to return a reference to `data`.
- A `peek` method can be implemented to return a reference to the top element.
- The constraint of the items in the max heap should be `Ord` rather than `PartialOrd`.
- There is no need to explicitly specify the types. For example the `usize` from this can be removed: `let new_node_index: usize = ...`.
- I would use `if` rather than `match` in the `pop` method.
- The two returns in `calculate_larger_child_index` can be removed to keep it consistent with the other methods.

Code with changes:

```rust
pub mod binary_heap {

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct MaxHeap<T> {
        data: Vec<T>,
    }

    impl<T> MaxHeap<T>
    where
        T: Ord,
    {
        pub fn new() -> MaxHeap<T> {
            MaxHeap { data: vec![] }
        }

        pub fn peek(&self) -> &T {
            &self.data[0]
        }

        pub fn as_vec(&self) -> &Vec<T> {
            &self.data
        }

        pub fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
            self.data.push(value);
            let new_node_index = self.data.len() - 1;
            self.sift_up(new_node_index);
        }

        pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
            if !self.data.is_empty() {
                let deleted_node = self.data.swap_remove(0);
                self.sift_down();
                Some(deleted_node)
            } else {
                None
            }
        }

        fn sift_up(&mut self, mut new_node_index: usize) {
            while !self.is_root(new_node_index) && self.is_greater_than_parent(new_node_index) {
                let parent_index = self.parent_index(new_node_index);
                self.data.swap(parent_index, new_node_index);
                new_node_index = self.parent_index(new_node_index);
            }
        }

        fn is_root(&self, node_index: usize) -> bool {
            node_index == 0
        }

        fn is_greater_than_parent(&self, node_index: usize) -> bool {
            let parent_index = self.parent_index(node_index);
            self.data[node_index] > self.data[parent_index]
        }

        fn sift_down(&mut self) {
            let mut sifted_down_node_index: usize = 0;

            while self.has_greater_child(sifted_down_node_index) {
                let larger_child_index = self.calculate_larger_child_index(sifted_down_node_index);
                self.data.swap(sifted_down_node_index, larger_child_index);
                sifted_down_node_index = larger_child_index;
            }
        }

        fn left_child_index(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
            (index * 2) + 1
        }

        fn right_child_index(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
            (index * 2) + 2
        }

        fn parent_index(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
            (index - 1) / 2
        }

        fn has_greater_child(&self, index: usize) -> bool {
            let left_child_index = self.left_child_index(index);
            let right_child_index = self.right_child_index(index);

            self.data.get(left_child_index).is_some()
                && self.data[left_child_index] > self.data[index]
                || self.data.get(right_child_index).is_some()
                    && self.data[right_child_index] > self.data[index]
        }

        fn calculate_larger_child_index(&self, index: usize) -> usize {
            let left_child_index = self.left_child_index(index);
            let right_child_index = self.right_child_index(index);

            let left_child = self.data.get(left_child_index);
            let right_child = self.data.get(right_child_index);

            if ((right_child.is_some() && left_child.is_some()) && right_child > left_child)
                || left_child.is_none()
            {
                right_child_index
            } else {
                left_child_index
            }
        }
    }

    #[cfg(test)]
    mod test {
        use super::*;

        #[test]
        fn push_test() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(3);
            heap.push(2);

            assert_eq!(&vec![3, 2], heap.as_vec());
        }

        #[test]
        fn root_node_is_always_the_biggest_element_in_heap_after_push_test() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(5);
            heap.push(10);
            heap.push(2);

            assert_eq!(&10, heap.peek());

            heap.push(3);

            assert_eq!(&10, heap.peek());

            heap.push(20);

            assert_eq!(&20, heap.peek());
        }

        #[test]
        fn pop_always_pop_the_root_node() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(10);
            heap.push(4);
            heap.push(7);

            heap.pop();

            assert!(!heap.as_vec().contains(&10));
        }

        #[test]
        fn pop_returns_a_variant_of_the_option_enum() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(10);

            assert_eq!(Some(10), heap.pop());
            assert_eq!(None, heap.pop());
        }

        #[test]
        fn root_node_is_always_the_biggest_element_in_heap_after_pop_test() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<i32> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push(5);
            heap.push(10);
            heap.push(2);

            heap.pop();

            assert_eq!(&5, heap.peek());

            heap.pop();

            assert_eq!(&2, heap.peek());
        }

        #[test]
        fn heap_is_generic_over_some_type_t() {
            let mut heap: MaxHeap<(i32, String)> = MaxHeap::new();
            heap.push((2, String::from("Zanzibar")));
            heap.push((10, String::from("Porto")));
            heap.push((5, String::from("Beijing")));

            let element = heap.pop();

            assert_eq!(Some((10, String::from("Porto"))), element);
            assert_eq!((5, String::from("Beijing")), heap.data[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Further possible improvements:

- Implement the `Iterator` and/or `IntoIterator` trait for `MaxHeap`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I implemented all of your comments in the original source code!
Why should the heap use `Ord` rather than `PartialOrd`?

Comment: Using `PartialOrd` means that not all values will have defined order and using `>`, `<`, etc. operators with such values will always return `false`.
For example both `f64::NAN < 0.5` and `f64::NAN > 0.5` return `false`, which can lead to inconsistencies in your data structure.
You can still use `PartialOrd` as a  constraint, as long as you either check the values before insertion and reject the ones that cannot be ordered or you define a custom ordering for them (for example treat them as smaller/larger than every other value).